# Rest Assured support for "text/csv" response

Tags: rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using Rest assured to send GET request .
The repose is "text/csv" type, is there a way to extract one element value from the csv file using Rest Assured

Scenario : I would like to get only "colors" from below CSV Response

Car ;wheels ;color ;airbags
alto ;4 ;red ;2
Benz ;4 ;blue ;1
Polo ;4 ;white ;1
swift ;4 ;red ;4

Answer (score 0):

RestAssured can parse xml and json by default.
Solution for you is to add custom parser for your response type and use response object mapping. See this [topic](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#object-mapping).